# Android App Icon Issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I recently made an app for android using android studio and set the icon and put it on my phone.

The problem is in the app list the icon appears as the android logos face, but when I manage the app, the icon is correct, and when on my phone I look at the apk its also correct.

Only on the app list is it incorrect.

What I've checked so far is:

Right Click the folder system, `New` > `New` > `Item asset`.
Set this as the application app and the image i want.

Also in the `AndroidManifest.xml` I've also set the

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

and on the left, the little image appears.

Any other idea's would be appreciated.

Thanks

If any other info is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

instead of ic_launcher put your drawable name in manifest

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick response. I'd named the new icon the same as the original and over-write it. I also made 1 with a different name and adjusted the name in android:icon= accordingly, but still no luck.

Comment: Have you placed the drawable in "drawable" folder

Comment: Yes I've tried that, and the icon in the app manager list on my phone does show the correct image. Its only on the app menu is it the android face. It's not even the full body like the default icon.

Comment: Can you send the screen shot of the drawable file structure

Comment: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2h4mdd2.jpg
http://i57.tinypic.com/walrir.jpg

2nd pic is the screenshot from phone.

Comment: I saw in the screenshot that there is some error in manifest. "MainActivity" i s shown in red color. R files wont build properly if there is any error in xml files. R file is responsible for mapping drawables

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have created app icons for all different DPI's.  If you check in your res folder there will be multiple drawable folders, suffixed with the different DPI's such as hdpi, xhdpi etc.

You will have to create versions of your icon for each of the different sizes as the OS will pull the most relevant size for what it needs to display at the time, small ones for the manage app's list, larger ones for your launcher.

There's a handy web tool to do this
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

As a side note, the lastest android studio and the above web tool uses a mipmap folder rather than drawable for application icons, you can either just copy the images into their relevant drawable folders or change your manifest to use the @mipmap prefix.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick response. I have all the versions in place and I've tried changing the drawable to mipmap with the icons there. But no change.

Comment: I'll post it when I get home tonight. Thanks

Comment: Seeing the screenshots you posted I would recommend creating a seperate ic_launcher using the tool I linked to above and copy the mipmap's from the zip file into your res folder then changing the manifest to android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"  that way you will have scaled resources for all screen resolutions.  Even if you get your current method working it will scale horribly on different devices.